# C# - Send HttpWebRequest to remote upload image?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, connection, keep-alive

For several days I've tried to write a program that remote upload image to an image host (imgur.com). I used Wireshark to sniff http requests sent by browser, then create HttpWebRequest with similar headers and parameters. But the server always send back to me something weird. Please look at the code (this code is simplified):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        List<string> formData = new List<string>();

        //The first request - login
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://imgur.com/signin");
        configRequest(request, cc);
        //add POST params
        add(formData, "username", "abcdefgh"); //this is a working account,
        add(formData, "password", "abcdefgh"); //feel free to use it if you 
        add(formData, "remember", "remember"); //want to test
        add(formData, "submit", "");
        writeToRequestStream(request, formData);
        //send request
        request.GetResponse();

        //The second request - remote upload image
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://imgur.com/upload?sid_hash=9efff36179fef47dc5e078a4575fd96a");
        configRequest(request, cc);
        //add POST params
        formData = new List<string>();
        add(formData, "url", "http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/8425/89948070152259768406.jpg");
        add(formData, "create_album", "0");
        add(formData, "album_title", "Optional Album Title");
        add(formData, "album_layout", "b");
        add(formData, "edit_url", "0");
        writeToRequestStream(request, formData);
        //send request
        Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();s.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(html + "\n\n");
    }
    static void add(List<string> formData, string key, string value)
    {
        formData.Add(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
    }
    static void configRequest(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer cc)
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Referer = "http://imgur.com/";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "115");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }
    static void writeToRequestStream(HttpWebRequest request, List<string> formData)
    {
        //build request stream
        string queryString = String.Join("&", formData.ToArray());
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
        //write to stream
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream rs = request.GetRequestStream();
        rs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        rs.Close();
    }
```

Now I sniff my uploading request (2nd request) and compare it to the browser's request, there're only 2 differences:

- Browser's 'Connection' header ='keep-alive' but mine doesn't exist (I don' know why although request.Keep-alive is set to 'true')
- Some browser's cookies doesn't appear in mine.

The response should be a JSON, something like this:

```
{"hashes":"[\"QcvII\"]","hash":"QcvII","album":false,"edit":false}
```

But the server responses to my request by a pile of special characters... I can't find out which in above 2 differences makes my code doesn't work. I will extremely appreciate if you can help me making this code work. I'm a newbie so please don't blame me if my code or my expression's silly.

Can anybody help to make this code work?

P/S: i'm using .net framework 4

Comment: You're ignoring the response to the login request. It likely has cookies and session information that you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the sid_hash url parameter in your attempt to upload the image is a session id that needs to change when you log in.

Comment: it seems to be so... 
But in your opinion, how can I find out that sid_hash? I've sniffed the requests again, save all the cookie values, but I couldn't find out the relation of that sid_hash to the previous server ID or session ID... Is there any operation to calculate that sid_hash?

Comment: Use the debugger to look at the response headers.  I'll give it a shot and let you know if I find anything

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I've found out the solution, fortunately. Forget all things in my function configRequest() (except 3 first lines), they just make things go wrong. The solution is, after sending the login request, send another request to the homepage (no parameter needed, but remember to include the cookies received from the 1st request). The sid_hash can be found in the returned HTML. Use that sid_hash to make the remote uploading request.

Thank you all, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your code, but [ClipUpload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipupload/) is an open source project that seems to already do about what you want:

> Quickly upload anything thats on your clipboard to the internet. It supports FTP, Imgur.com, Pastebin.com and SendSpace.com. Usage? Step 1: Copy. Step 2: Click system tray icon. Step 3: Paste public link. The easiest way to share your clipboard!

Comment: thanks, but it seems to be not what I need. What I'm trying to do is remote uploading, not upload image from local computer. Anyway, I will check out their code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the second request contains the session ID cookies. Without those cookies, server will not be able to recognise you hence upload will not work.

You can set the keep-alive yourself but my suggestion is to post snippet of the response headers to the first request so we could help.

---

### UPDATE

According to your updates, you need to include this cookie:

```
IMGURSESSION=iliutpm33rhl2rugn5vcr8jq60
```

Obviously the value will change with each logging.

Comment: Here're some of response headers to the login request (made by browser)

Cache-Control: max-age=7200, must-revalidate

Set-Cookie: authautologin=0c55363d70643ced345006a4d9fe93f6548aebf5%7ERlw7ghczzELpdoO5beHxOGbYf09aSRE4; expires=Fri, 01-Apr-2011 15:50:40 GMT; path=/

Set-Cookie: IMGURSESSION=iliutpm33rhl2rugn5vcr8jq60; path=/; domain=.imgur.com

...

Comment: And this's response to request made by my code:

Set-Cookie: IMGURSESSION=7lema8q57loftnlvj2baifmks5; path=/; domain=.imgur.com

Cache-Control: max-age=7200, must-revalidate

Set-Cookie: authautologin=7cf9476bba0ea6729064dd3b8ab02571f738a562%7EjSBYQzpL3IBbFwPWECoDdpKGKWcsIzxP; expires=Fri, 01-Apr-2011 15:53:50 GMT; path=/

Set-Cookie: IMGURSESSION=0kfm0kts43dnlbgd6ojr8h3985; path=/; domain=.imgur.com

Set-Cookie: SERVERID=www2; path=/

Please tell me if you need more information...

Comment: actually I've always sent the cookies received from the 1st response along with the 2nd request, as you can see in the code:

request.CookieContainer = cc;

What I'm thinking of now is the sid_hash. Whether it has some relationship with IMGURSESSION or something else?